# How to properly bind parameters to Doctrine Criteria expr() method?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In a Doctrine Criteria instance, I have some static parameters, that I  wrote directly in the query as below :

```php
    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria
     */
    public function lastContratCriteria()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();

        $baseCondition = $criteria->expr()->andX(
          $criteria->expr()->eq('BaseType', 1), // STATIC VALUE 
          $criteria->expr()->orX(
            $criteria->expr()->gt('dateFinContractuellePrevue','CURRENT_DATE()'), // STATIC VALUE 
            $criteria->expr()->isNull('dateFinContractuellePrevue')
          )
        );

        $criteria
          ->andWhere($baseCondition)
          ->orderBy(['dateDebut' => 'DESC'])
          ->setMaxResults(1);

        return $criteria;
    }
```

But this throws:

> QueryException : *Too few parameters: the query defines 2 parameters but you bound 0*.

This is the DQL output, where you can see bound params based on property name (which I did not defined) :

```
WHERE contrat.BaseType = :BaseType AND (contrat.dateFinContractuellePrevue > :dateFinContractuellePrevue OR contrat.dateFinContractuellePrevue IS NULL)
```

I could not find in the docs why my static params were not used. To debug , I changed the static values to bound parameters :

```php
     $baseCondition = $criteria->expr()->andX(
          $criteria->expr()->eq('BaseType', ':bType'),
          $criteria->expr()->orX(
            $criteria->expr()->gt('dateFinContractuellePrevue',':dateFinCP'),
            $criteria->expr()->isNull('dateFinContractuellePrevue')
          )
     );
```

But **No matter how I named the parameters**, to make it work I had to call each one in `setParameter()` **with its correspondent property name** instead of the custom name I choose :

```
->setParameter('BaseType', 1) // Should be bType as above, not BaseType ?
->setParameter('dateFinContractuellePrevue', 'CURRENT_DATE()') // Should be :dateFinCP ?
```

### Here's the complete query :

```php
    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria
     */
    public function lastContratCriteria()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();

        $baseCondition = $criteria->expr()->andX(
          $criteria->expr()->eq('BaseType', ':bType'),
          $criteria->expr()->orX(
            $criteria->expr()->gt('dateFinContractuellePrevue',':dateFinCP'),
            $criteria->expr()->isNull('dateFinContractuellePrevue')
          )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
     */
    public function getCurrentContratQB()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('contrat')
              ->addCriteria($this->lastContratCriteria());
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
     */
    public function getSeminaire()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('salarie')
          ->andWhere('salarie.archive = FALSE')

          ->leftJoin('salarie.contrats', 'c')
          ->addSelect('c') 

          ->andWhere("c.id IN (". $this->contratRepository->getCurrentContratQB() .")")

          //  ONLY ORIGINAL FIELD NAME IS RECOGNIZED HERE, not the bound parameter name
          ->setParameter('BaseType', 1) // Should be bType, not BaseType
          ->setParameter('dateFinContractuellePrevue', 'CURRENT_DATE()') // Should be :dateFinCP

        //dump($qb->getDQL());

        return $qb->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
    }
```

Why can't I pass static values in `$criteria->expr()->eq()` ? Why is Doctrine demanding me to set parameters with the exact name of the queried property instead of taking care of the parameters I named ?

Comment: Your function lastContratCriteria() does not contain information on which parameter to bind, thus it has no clue about what ':bType' would be. lastContratCriteria($baseType,$dateFinCP) would work as long as you are binding them inside function with  ->eq('BaseType', $baseType) directly. I don't think its directly possible to do it with expression builder. Correct me if I'm wrong, but expressions are specifically designed to work with values, as you can see here [Expression Builder Class](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ExpressionBuilder.html)

Comment: @MaulikParmar, tks. I added further explanations to the question. `lastContratCriteria()` does not contain information on which parameter to bind because  there is no `setParameter` method in Criteria class and the parameters are expected at the query root level. IMHO `lastContratCriteria($baseType,$dateFinCP)`  would be a non sense ?

Comment: Not if you are passing values directly from outside when you call function. That's exactly what expression builder is expecting.

Comment: It seems your updated solution should work as long as you are not binding any parameters. Have you tried cleaning caches and run it again?

Comment: @MaulikParmar, indeed it was already working when I posted the question. I try to understand this weird behavior, and make sure I'm not making THE big mistake. I could write `$criteria->expr()->eq('BaseType', ':whatAboutAFreshBeer')`, it would work either. The actual code just takes care that I have as many params as Criteria comparisons set at query root level (not Criteria neither subquery), and that they have the exact field name ! Weird weird weird ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need the DQL of the subquery to add it inside another querybuilder and expose the original parameter names.

Try replacing

`->andWhere("c.id IN (". $this->contratRepository->getCurrentContratQB() .")")`

with

`->andWhere("c.id IN (". $this->contratRepository->getCurrentContratQB()->getDQL() .")")`

or

`; $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in("c.id", $this->contratRepository->getCurrentContratQB()->getDQL())`